# Open Pdf link android

Tags: android, pdf, sdk

I have to show a PDF file inside my application and the PDF file contains a link inside (this link sends the user to the website).

I am searching for a library that allows me to show the file inside my application and if the user clicks the link, open a browser.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use this one : [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer)

you can use a webview also following this example : [Example pdf on webview](http://weimenglee.blogspot.fr/2013/05/android-tip-displaying-pdf-document.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used this library but the rendered file does not allow to click the links.  I need the following: If the user clicks one link inside the file, a browser must be opened (with the referred url in the link)

In the other hand, the other option is not an possibility, because the pdf file must be opened inside the application.

Comment: the second option allows you to open a webview inside the application

Comment: With the new verision (3.0.0-beta.1) of AndroidPdfViewer, this is resolved. :) thanks a lot!